# Stripe SetupIntent update flow for a new PaymentMethod

Tags: stripe-payments

We are creating a site that allows users to attach a card to future payments.

At the first attempt, we're creating a **SetupIntent** with a **PaymentMethod** (card) - *https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse*.

Now let's say that user whats to remove the current card and attach a new one.
We can't change assigned payment method to **SetupIntent** or cancel **SetupIntent**, because

> "You cannot cancel this SetupIntent because it has a status of succeeded."

Maybe I don't understand something, but how can I allow user to remove a card and attach a new one in **save-and-reuse** example?

Or maybe it was designed in such a way that **SetupIntent** only supports **PaymentMethod** authentication, and for a new card it is enough to disconnect (detach) the current **PaymentMethod**, leave **SetupIntent** unchanged and create a new **SetupIntent** + **PaymentMethod** pair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've setup a PaymentMethod via a SetupIntent, you no longer do anything through that SetupIntent (`successful` is a terminal state). You would [detach the PaymentMethod from the Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/detach) later, and/or you would follow the SetupIntent flow again (with a new SetupIntent) if you want to add a different/new PaymentMethod later.

Comment: annoying how they don't let you cancel once you have one.. prob some weird reason. SO just update the payment_method to null?